# issue related to android treeview

Tags: java, android

Trying to implement the android treeview into project. But its showing

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication.holder.IconTreeItemHolder$IconTreeItem
>           at com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication.holder.IconTreeItemHolder.createNodeView(IconTreeItemHolder.java:12)

calling IconTreeItemHolder.java from a fragment.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_default, container, false);
        ViewGroup containerView = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        TreeNode root = TreeNode.root();
        TreeNode pkm = new TreeNode("Personal Knowledge Management");
        TreeNode personal = new TreeNode("Personal");
        TreeNode knowledge = new TreeNode("Knowledge");
        TreeNode management = new TreeNode("Management");
        pkm.addChildren(personal, knowledge, management);
        root.addChild(pkm);
        tView = new AndroidTreeView(getActivity(), root);
        tView.setDefaultAnimation(true);
        tView.setDefaultContainerStyle(R.style.TreeNodeStyleCustom);
        tView.setDefaultViewHolder(IconTreeItemHolder.class);
        tView.setDefaultNodeClickListener(nodeClickListener);
        tView.setDefaultNodeLongClickListener(nodeLongClickListener);
        containerView.addView(tView.getView());
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String state = savedInstanceState.getString("tState");
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(state)) {
                tView.restoreState(state);
            }
        }
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: The line number mentioned states there is somewhere a class cast to String, which is failing.